Trying to make a reative dataset available in ui
I'm learning about Shiny and keep running into the following issue.

server contain a data set.

It is used with reactive to filter on variables that the user may use ( filtered_data_1 )

the ui part keeos throwing the following error
Error in unique(MyDT$AsOfDate) : object 'MyDT' not found


The error makes sense. I create the reactive piece in server but the ui knows nothing about it.
how can i resolve this?
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  MyDT <-
    structure(list(MinuteOfDay = structure(c(1716379200, 1716379500,
                                             1716379800, 1716380100, 1716380400, 1716380700, 1716381000, 1716381300,
                                             1716381600, 1716381900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
                   AgentCategory = c("Core", "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core",
                                     "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core", "Core"), variable = structure(c(1L,
                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Queue",
                                                                                                                                                     "Login", "Tier", "Abr_Actuals", "Abr_Preds", "Abr_Diff"), class = "factor"),
                   value = c(2, 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 0, 4), AsOfDate = structure(c(19865,
                                                                                   19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865, 19865
                   ), class = "Date"), MinuteOfDay_TIME = structure(c(25200,
                                                                      25500, 25800, 26100, 26400, 26700, 27000, 27300, 27600, 27900
                   ), units = "secs", class = c("hms", "difftime"))), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                    -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

 
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
   
    filtered_data_1 <- reactive({
      subset(MyDT,
             as.Date(MyDT$AsOfDate) %in% as.Date(input$Date1) &
               as.character(MyDT$variable) %in% as.character(input$Metric1))
    })

    ggplot(data = filtered_data_1(),
           aes(x = MinuteOfDay,
               y = value)) +
      geom_point(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
      geom_line(stat = "identity", linewidth = 1.6, col = "red") +
      labs(x = "MinuteOfDay", y = input$Metric1) +
      ggtitle(paste0("Time Series: ", input$Metric1, sep = "")) +
      theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size=16, face= "bold", colour= "black", hjust = 0.5, margin = margin(t=10,b=-20)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=16, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=14, face="bold", colour = "black"), # bold
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black" ),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size = 14, face="bold", colour = "black"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.3),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA)
      )  +
      theme_classic()  
   
  })

}


#===============================================================================

message("app: Create UI  \n")

ui <- fluidPage(
 
  titlePanel("ABR Dashboard"),
 
  tabsetPanel(      
   
    tabPanel("Time Series",
             sidebarLayout(
               selectInput(inputId = "Date1",
                           label = "Select Date",
                           choices = unique(MyDT$AsOfDate)
               ),
               selectInput(inputId = "Metric1",
                           label = "Which Metric",
                           choices = unique(MyDT$variable)
               )
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput("distPlot1")
             )
    )
  )
)

#===============================================================================

message("app: Import Packages \n")

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

#===============================================================================


Since the data is present in server you would need to update the dropdown via server.
Use updateSelectInput
Here are the changes that you need to do in your app.
In ui make choices as blank.
tabPanel("Time Series",
             sidebarLayout(
               selectInput(inputId = "Date1",
                           label = "Select Date", 
                           choices = ""
               ),
               selectInput(inputId = "Metric1",
                           label = "Which Metric", 
                           choices = ""
               )
             ),


and in server update the values.
updateSelectInput(session, "Metric1", choices = MyDT$variable)
updateSelectInput(session, "Date1", choices = MyDT$AsOfDate)

Another option would be to render the entire dropdown using renderUI/uiOutput from server.
